# CSS - Full width circle shape with text ontop

Tags: html, css

so i'm trying to recreate this design here:
[Website design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEtlp.jpg)

So the red circle is super-wide and bleeding off the side of the screen.
And then I want text ontop, which will be my website logo.

I've had a good go at it here:
https://jsfiddle.net/s0q8Ljr5/1/

---

```
#container {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
}

#nav-bg {
width: 90vw;
height: 90vw;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
margin-top: -45vw;
background: red;
border-radius: 50%;
position: absolute;
}

#title {
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 20px;
}
```

---

But as you can see, I can't get the circle to go as wide as I want it whilst keeping it central.
The text isn't central.
And tbh i'm not sure using the "vw" property for width and height is very cross-browser compatible.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use SVG to achieve it, clip-path too. there are lots of ways to create this, check this one

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.nextDiv {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.cutEffect {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(-90%);
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="nav-bg"></div>
  <h1 id="title">Title goes here</h1>
</div>
<div class="nextDiv">
  <svg class="cutEffect" viewBox="0 0 100 20" fill="white">
    <path d="M 0 0 L 0 20 L 100 20 L 100 0 Q 50 30 0 0"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You have used viewport properties, however I see you have used same for both height and width. Ideally it should different for `width(vw)` and `height(vh)`

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#nav-bg {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: -45vh;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 60%;
  position: relative;
}

#title {
  top: 65%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="nav-bg"></div>
  <h1 id="title">Title goes here</h1>

</div>
```

You can do something like this: